# Making a decision tree for AI in C++

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence

I know the basics of having a user input their decision as a choice, and having that lead to another decision. My only issue is that when i make these choices, it is almost all hard coded in, leaving no room for other uses of the code. I was wondering what the best way to make a decision tree for AI that would allow them to make smart decisions based on the circumstances. I DO NOT want the pre-written code or a library. I would prefer to write the code myself and learn more about the language. I have a good understanding of the language, but would still like to learn more.

Comment: Use recursion. Imagine you have a program that moves blocks around on a table. To move each block, it has to make sure it has no blocks on top of it, which means moving those blocks too. Basically code functions that work in any situation, and that perform only small steps (mostly these steps will be to know which functions to call).

Comment: Sounds like you want to do some machine learning to build the decision tree, which is great because that is one of the first examples done in any machine learning course! The gist is that you have to provide a set of scenarios as well as actions to take for each scenario, and the machine will eventually predict the correct actions based on the scenario. Later scenarios can therefore also be predicted with the correct actions. The difficult part will be deciding how to represent your scenarios and actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embed a scripting language (e.g. [Lua](http://www.lua.org/)) into your application and let your users write their decision trees as scripts.

Or you can think of some data structure (XML-based for example) that describes an arbitrary decision tree that you can parse and build the actual tree during run time.

Comment: I know a bit of Lua, but would i say use it to allow the user to create say a custom AI? or would i just use Lua for each decision?

Comment: Devilswin, well, it is actually depends on what you want to achieve. But it is of course possible to implement an AI with a scripting language (that's what they do in video games).